# Why is Facebook converting & to &amp; in my Open Graph image meta-tag?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, url, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, ampersand

Facebook has stopped displaying my `og:image` meta-tag correctly. It was fine on Thursday and Friday, but not today.

My `og:image` uri includes ampersands which are **definitely** output as `&` (rather than `&amp;`) - I have checked 'View Source' and even temporarily hardcoded a uri.

But when they go through Facebook's [Open Graph Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) (and presumably by Facebook itself because my posts have no images) they appear as `&amp;`.

Here is a meta-tag from 'View Source' of my site:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/xc/455365166.jpg?v=2&c=IWSAsset&k=2" />
```

Here is how it is read by the Facebook Open Graph Debugger:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/xc/455365166.jpg?v=2&amp;c=IWSAsset&amp;k=2" />
```

Does anyone know why this should be? Has anyone else encountered the issue? Have Facebook changed anything in the past few days?

I have trawled through the [Facebook API docs](http://developers.facebook.com) and a number of SO questions, but nothing matches my issue.

How can I resolve this? How can I stop Facebook converting my `&` to `&amp;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erm, ok, it is working again today - I've not changed anything.

[shakes fist at Facebook]

Comment: well its happening again now

Comment: did you ever figure this out @gondo

Comment: @SeanMC no sorry

Comment: I found it was my own API that was doing it -so I wrote some extra code to undo it and problem solved, in my case